# "No connection" reported on Iris By Lowe's Android app for WIFI-enabled Whirlpool Water Softener (WHESCS)

Tags: smart-home, wifi

Not sure what caused it, but my water softener stopped connecting to the Iris app recently. Has anyone found an easy solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the Lowe's troubleshooting steps recommend re-pairing the unit to the Iris hub via WIFI, I found a much easier method.

Lowe's recommends tapping the Tank Light five times on the water softener unit itself to reset this WIFI-enabled device, then follow the pairing instructions on the Iris app to repair the device (see video instructions at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhJQXagqjTg).

However, I tried just unplugging the power cord from the wall socket for ten seconds and then plugging it back in, and that fixed it right up without having to go through the complex re-pairing process!

Comment: Note that this only works where the connection has been dropped (usually as the result of a power outage, and the endpoint timing out before the WiFi network is up again). It is more a 'forced re-associate' than anything else.